# I want to show facebook home page in my asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, fbml

I want to show all the details (user picture,all photo,comment,friends wall) in my asp.net facebook application .

Comment: What have you tried? What is it that's not working for you? It is easier to answer a question if the question is clear.

Comment: I want a pony. (And why in the world are you re-writing Facebook in ASP.NET? That site is already on the web.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Facebook developer site and read the information there.  It has all of this information: http://developers.facebook.com/

You need to figure out what type of app you want to develop, if it will reside in Facebook, or if it will be your own personal site that retrieves facebook info.  The latter is referred to as Facebook Connect, which has some variances over a Facebook app.